# R functional programming: using apply family to calculate kernel matrix for gaussian processes

Tags: r, machine-learning, functional-programming, apply, lapply

## My Minimal Working Example

Here is my minimal working example (notice I've simplified the mathematics). Suppose I have a function of two variables where `x` and `y` are two vectors of the same dimension.

```
kernel_func <- function(x, y){
    return(sum((x - y)^2))
}
```

I also have two matrices with different number of rows, but same number of columns.

- A matrix `X` of dimension `n` times `d`
- A matrix `Y` of dimension `m` times `d`

Now I would like to obtain a matrix, call it `K`, whose i,j element is calculated by passing the `i`th row of `X` as the first argument to `kernel_func` and the `j`th row of `Y` as the second argument. That is

```
kernel_func(X[i, ], Y[j, ])
```

How can I write a concise piece of code that does this, hopefully using `apply`, `lapply`, `mapply` or similar?

## Stupid MWE

Create the two matrices with the same number of columns

```
X = matrix(1:9, nrow=3, ncol=3)
Y = matrix(1:12, nrow=4, ncol=3)
```

Initiate the `K` matrix with zeros

```
K <- matrix(0, nrow(X), nrow(Y))
```

Use a double loop to create the matrix

```
for (i in rep(1:nrow(X), 4)){
    for (j in 1:nrow(Y)) {
        K[i, j] = kernel_func(X[i, ], Y[j, ])
    }
}
```

Comment: `apply(Y, 1, function(y) apply(X, 1, kernel_func, y))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two approaches to make it:

- Solution with `apply()`:

```
K <- t(apply(X, 1, function(p) apply(Y, 1, function(q) kernel_func(p,q))))
```

- Solution with `expand.grid()`:

```
K <- matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:nrow(X),1:nrow(Y)),1, 
                  function(k) kernel_func(X[k[1],],Y[k[2],])),nrow = nrow(X))
```

**Output**

```
> K
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   14   29   50
[2,]    2    5   14   29
[3,]    5    2    5   14
```